# Create unique ID from the existing two columns, python

Tags: python, pandas, unique-id

My question is: how to efficiently sign data unique id numbers from existing id columns? For example: I have two columns [household_id], and [person_no]. I try to make a new column, the query would be: household_id + '_' + person_no.

here is a sample:

```
hh_id       pno  
 682138    1   
 365348    1     
 365348    2
```

try to get:

```
unique_id
682138_1
365348_1
365348_2
```

and add this unique_id as a new column. 
I am applying Python. My data is very large. Any efficient way to do it would be great. Thanks!

Comment: A new column _of what_? Are you working with CSV data? A database? A data analysis tool like Pandas or NumPy?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/).

Assuming your data is in a csv file, read in the data:

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', delim_whitespace=True)
```

Create the new id column:

```
df['unique_id'] = df.hh_id.astype(str) + '_' + df.pno.astype(str)
```

Now `df` looks like this:

```
    hh_id  pno unique_id
0  682138    1  682138_1
1  365348    1  365348_1
2  365348    2  365348_2
```

Write back to a csv file:

```
df.to_csv('out.csv', index=False)
```

The file content looks like this:

```
hh_id,pno,unique_id
682138,1,682138_1
365348,1,365348_1
365348,2,365348_2
```

Comment: Thank you, Mike! The data stored as DataFrame. I tried: test['id'] = test.apply(lambda row: (row['hh_id'].astype(str) + '_' + row['pno'].astype(str)), axis=1) Got error: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3596, in apply
    return self._apply_standard(f, axis, reduce=reduce)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3686, in _apply_standard
    results[i] = func(v)
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
TypeError: ('data type not understood', u'occurred at index 0')

Comment: Did you try my suggested solution `test['unique_id'] = test.hh_id.astype(str) + '_' + test.pno.astype(str)`?